# Почему не работают CSS + jQuery которые подклчюены WordPress?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, плагин

Скрипты и стили подклчюены верно ( првоерил в header они там есть, пути к ним прописаны верно и файлы те что нужны ). Подключаю Lightbox для хувер еффекта галлереии которою склепал. И тут, бац, не работает, хотя и загружены... Почему? Ето как так? 
Вот мой код:

```
    function lightbox_connect() {
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'lightbox_js', '/wp-content/plugins/view_post_imgs/js/lightbox.js', array( 'jquery' ));
wp_enqueue_script( 'lightbox_js' );

wp_register_style( 'lightbox_css', '/wp-content/plugins/view_post_imgs/css/lightbox.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'lightbox_css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'lightbox_connect' );

add_action('get_fotos');
function get_fotos(){

$gt3_theme_pagebuilder = gt3_get_theme_pagebuilder(get_the_ID());
$fotos_array = $gt3_theme_pagebuilder["post-formats"]["images"];
       foreach ($fotos_array as $genera_array => $foto_id_array) {
        foreach ($foto_id_array as $foto_id){
          echo '
    <a class="example-image-link" href="'.wp_get_attachment_image_url ($foto_id).'" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward.">
      <img class="example-image" src="'.wp_get_attachment_image_url ($foto_id).'" alt=""/>
    </a>
          ';
        }
      }

}
```

Comment: Что именно не работает? Какие ошибки в консоли браузера?

Comment: Сталкивался с такой ситуацией, рушил проблему путем метода тыка, а именно: убирал библиотеки и скрипты по очереди и в разной последовательности. Причина была в том, что скрипты или библиотеки  не хотели работать одновременно друг с другом, при удалении лишнего оба функционала работали нормально.

Comment: `function new_jquery() { 
 wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-core' );
 wp_register_script( 'jquery-core', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js');
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'new_jquery' );`
Вот так нужно подключать jquery, ибо по дефолту он уже есть, но версия старая.

Comment: проблема была в конфликте скриптов, загрузил часть скриптов в footer все заработало. В то же время, если грузил в фуутер все, ничего не работало, надо было загрузить только часть...